# What should I think of a diverging beta function (in Renormalisation Group flow)?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, statistical-mechanics, renormalization, singularities, effective-field-theory

I have written a set of RG flow equations using [Functional Renormalization Group](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Functional_renormalization_group) methods. I am looking at the flow of a well known problem with an additional original coupling. I did not do anything systematic. The first step of my work is just to see if my new coupling grows under iteration of the RG flow.

I find something strange and have no idea how (and if) I should interpret it: For a large set of initial conditions, the RG flow goes towards a point where the beta functions diverge. The RG flow stops at a finite cut-off value (that depends on the initial conditions) and is not defined below that.

I am looking into the RG flow of the $O(N)$ model. I have included a 4-point coupling that contains two spatial derivatives. When the field expectation value $\rho_0$ is very small, one of the new couplings decouples from all the other couplings. I get the following beta functions
$$\beta_{\text{new}} = -\frac{4 \lambda_{\text{new}}}{\left(8\pi + \lambda_{\text{new}}\right) \rho_0} \, ,$$
$$\beta_{\rho_0} = 0 \, .$$
If this is initiated with $-8\pi<\lambda_{\text{new}}<0$, the flow equation
$$\partial_t\lambda_{\text{new}} = \beta_{\text{new}}\, ,$$
decreases $\lambda_{\text{new}}$ until it becomes equal to $-8\pi$ and the RG flow stops.

I find this very strange and do no know what do think about it. The only thing that I can think of is that my approximation scheme really bad and that I should not trust this part of my calculation. What do you think?

Comment: I don't know the answer, but it might be worth to say what problem exactly this appears in. It may well be that sometimes, it's an artifact of an approximation and other times, it's something physical (like a phase transition, perhaps?).

Comment: A diagram, if possible, might be useful as well.

Comment: Are you describing a Landau pole?

Comment: @innisfree It is not the coupling that diverges, it is the beta function. I don't think that it's a Landau pole. Please correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: Singularities may sometimes reflect bad coordinates... see if you could redefine that coupling to remove the pole. In some 2d sigma models [cf this one](https://www.researchgate.net/profile/Cosmas_Zachos/publication/223877745_Torsion_and_geometrostasis_in_nonlinear_sigma_models/links/09e4150aba5578993e000000.pdf) the beta function maps to the Ricci tensor of the group geometries. Divergence of the Ricci tensor might tell you something about the geometrical flow underlying the phenomenon.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is essentially a Landau pole. A Landau pole describes a renormalization group (RG) flow where the coupling diverges at a finite value of the renormalization scale (see, e.g., [Landau pole in Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quantum_triviality)). According to the classification of Bogoliubov and Shirkov (N. N. Bogoliubov; D. V. Shirkov (1980). Introduction to the Theory of Quantized Fields (3rd ed.). John Wiley & Sons.) if the beta function for a coupling $g$, $\beta_{g}$, scales like $g^{\alpha}$ with $\alpha>1$ at large values of $g$ then $g$ will have a Landau pole.

To see that $\lambda$ in the OP possesses, essentially, a Landau pole, it is convenient to switch variables to
\begin{equation}
h=\frac{1}{8\pi+\lambda}
\end{equation}
so that
\begin{equation}
\beta_h = \frac{4}{\rho_0}(1-8\pi h)h^2.
\end{equation}
Notice that, $\beta_h \sim h^3$ as $h$ becomes large (or as $\lambda$ approaches $-8\pi$ from above). Then, following the classification of Bogoliubov and Shirkov, $h$ has a Landau pole.